# MonoGame MonoDevelop Ubuntu (Elementary) installation

Tags: ubuntu, monodevelop, monogame

this is on ElementaryOS 0.4.1 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS AFAIR).

Onboard is MonoDevelop 5.x. Additionally I tried FlatPak and installed MonoDevelop 7.y.

When installing monogame throuth the .run file from their website, the installer reports:

MonoDevelop 6..................................[Not Found]

It seems to not recognize version 5. After installing 7 through flatpak and still not having the project templates I tried navigating to the monogame installation directory. Its not there.
I read about flatpak using some kind of container system, so I think this is because of flatpak. When using nautilus to browse the installation directory it is definitely there.

I haven't found a PPA containing either a proper monogame nor a proper and recent monodevelop.

The onboard version seems to be too old, the flatpak version is encapsulated, this is just stupid and I have no idea how go on now and need help.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but you can take a look at [this thread](http://community.monogame.net/t/installing-monogame-3-6-on-linux/8811). I don't know why they're not updating packages for distros... it's terrible and I'm not even bothering with it, really...

Comment: Terrible indeed. I already found it but I don't like running some install scripts where I can't control updates and remove software. I was hoping that anyone here would have found a better solution. But thank you for pointing that out.